# My totals are not adding up, but just staying as 0

Tags: loops

Whenever I run my code, all my totals end up as just zero. What am I missing?

```java
while (theaterNumber != -999)

childTicketInOneTotal += childTicketInOne;
adultTicketInOneTotal += adultTicketInOne;
childTicketInTwoTotal += childTicketInTwo;
adultTicketInTwoTotal += adultTicketInTwo;

if (theaterNumber == 1)

  {System.out.print("How many child tickets were sold?");
  childTicketInOne = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.print("How many adult tickets were sold?");
  adultTicketInOne = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Which theater was used (1 or 2)? Enter -999 to complete inputs.");
        theaterNumber = keyboard.nextInt();}

else if (theaterNumber == 2)

{System.out.print("How many child tickets were sold?");
  childTicketInTwo = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.print("How many adult tickets were sold?");
  adultTicketInTwo = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Which theater was used (1 or 2)? Enter -999 to complete inputs.");
        theaterNumber = keyboard.nextInt();}}

//Display totals
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Theater 1 Totals:");
System.out.println("Adult Tickets Sold: "+ adultTicketInOneTotal +"");    
System.out.println("Child Tickets Sold: "+ childTicketInOneTotal +"");
System.out.printf("Total Amount Made: $%.2f \n\n",  totalAmountTheaterOne);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Theater 2 Totals:");
System.out.println("Adult Tickets Sold: "+ adultTicketInTwoTotal +"");
System.out.println("Child Tickets Sold: "+ childTicketInTwoTotal +"");
System.out.printf("Total Amount Made: $%.2f \n\n",  totalAmountTheaterTwo);

}}
```

Comment: Is your while-loop correct?

Comment: There's no opening bracket after while loop i.e. { thats why loop is doing nothing.

Comment: What troubles me is that you say it actually "finishes". Since you use `while` without curly-brackets, it only executes the statement after. So if `theaterNumber != -999` is true, you would have an infinite loop, as `childTicketInOneTotal += childTicketInOne;` does not seem to alter `theaterNumber`. So it must be false. But if you added the proper curly-brackets, then it would still be false and your code would do nothing. Can you add more detail?

Answer (score 0):

What language is this?  You probably want to initialize your variables before the loop starts and add the input before the output, something like this:

```
childTicketInOneTotal = 0;
adultTicketInOneTotal = 0;
childTicketInTwoTotal = 0;
adultTicketInTwoTotal = 0;

while (theaterNumber != -999){

  if (theaterNumber == 1)

   {System.out.print("How many child tickets were sold?");
   childTicketInOne = keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.print("How many adult tickets were sold?");
   adultTicketInOne = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Which theater was used (1 or 2)? Enter -999 to complete inputs.");
    theaterNumber = keyboard.nextInt();}

  else if (theaterNumber == 2)

   {System.out.print("How many child tickets were sold?");

    childTicketInTwo = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("How many adult tickets were sold?");
    adultTicketInTwo = keyboard.nextInt();
  # end if not needed?

    System.out.print("Which theater was used (1 or 2)? Enter -999 to complete inputs.");
    theaterNumber = keyboard.nextInt();}}

   childTicketInOneTotal += childTicketInOne;
  adultTicketInOneTotal += adultTicketInOne;
  childTicketInTwoTotal += childTicketInTwo;
  adultTicketInTwoTotal += adultTicketInTwo;

  //Display totals
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Theater 1 Totals:");
  System.out.println("Adult Tickets Sold: "+ adultTicketInOneTotal +"");    
  System.out.println("Child Tickets Sold: "+ childTicketInOneTotal +"");
  System.out.printf("Total Amount Made: $%.2f \n\n",  totalAmountTheaterOne);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Theater 2 Totals:");
  System.out.println("Adult Tickets Sold: "+ adultTicketInTwoTotal +"");
  System.out.println("Child Tickets Sold: "+ childTicketInTwoTotal +"");
  System.out.printf("Total Amount Made: $%.2f \n\n",  totalAmountTheaterTwo);

}}
```